# Generating a JavaScript array from a PHP array

Tags: php, javascript

Suppose that I have a string `$var`:

```
//php code

$var = "hello,world,test";
$exp = explode(",",$var);
```

Now I get the array as `exp[0],exp[1],exp[1]` as `'hello'`, `'world'` and `'test'`, respectively.

I want to use this all value in javascript in this:

```
var name = ['hello','world','test'];
```

How can I generate that JavaScript in PHP?

Comment: Why on earth are you first loading values into vars in php and then overload them to javascript anyway?

Comment: var name = ($exp[0],$exp[1],$exp[2]); to be honest i don't know what you are asking, but this is what you do in your examples...

Comment: @Younes: It is helpful, sometimes... If you wan't to show, for example, a variable that is stored in a session with Javascript without firing a ajax request after the page is loaded.

Comment: @vipinsahu - could you take a moment to review Karl's answer, and accept it if it works for you - his is better than mine!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would have thought [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) would be the most reliable and simplest way.

E.g.

```
$var = "hello,world,test";
$exp = explode(",",$var);
print json_encode($exp);
```

Comment: +1 This the the best way to turn any PHP value into a JavaScript value literal. Remember to use at least the `JSON_HEX_TAG` flag if you are in a `<script>` block to avoid `</` in the string breaking the script block, or `JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP` for XHTML compatibility.

Comment: +1 from me too - didn't know about `json_encode` - can I suggest adding some sample code that the OP can use? Hopefully he'll then accept your answer instead, and I can delete mine.

Comment: Have added a bit of example code as recommended (and as I should have done in the first place).

Comment: Doesn't this generate a javascript object rather than an array?

Answer (score 5):

### Karl B's answer is better - use that!

Wouldn't an easier way be like this:

```
$var = "hello,world,test";
$var = str_replace(",", "','", $var);
```

Then wherever you're spitting out JavaScript (assuming you can use PHP there):

```
var name = ['<?php echo $var; ?>'];
```

This doesn't deal properly with quoted values though - if you want that, you're better off with using [`fgetscsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) et al.

If you're determined to use `explode`, then you can use its other-half, [`implode`](https://www.php.net/implode) like this in your output:

```
var name = ['<? php echo implode("','", $var); ?>'];
```

Comment: You should remember to escape quotes. If `$var = "he'llo,world"` then above code will fail. Use `array_walk($var, 'addslashes');` before `explode`.

Comment: String declarations in JavaScript are not the same as in PHP.