# Convert PHP array to JAVASCRIPT array

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating a JavaScript array from a PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109531/generating-a-javascript-array-from-a-php-array)

I just want to know how to create JavaScript array with the help of PHP and help are definitely appreciated

I have a PHP result to this form

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 11
            [name] => MLB
            [totalcount] => 4
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 35
            [name] => American Idol
            [totalcount] => 2
        )

)
```

and i want to convert this array to JavaScript array like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myData = new Array(['MLB', 4], ['American Idol', 2]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, convert your input array to the required format:

```
$new_data = array();
foreach( $original_data as $ori_row )
  $new_data[] = array( $ori_row->name, $ori_row->totalcount );
```

Now you can enjoy the benefits of `json_encode`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
$json = json_encode( $new_data );
echo <<<END
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var myData = $json;
  </script>
END;
```

By the way, you don't have to write `new Array(...)`, simply write `[...]`, just like your inner arrays.

I think I answered your question, see http://codepad.org/5guUWmHD

Comment: Read the question carefully - the OP wants an array - **not** a (JSON) object.

Comment: Read the documentation carefully - json_encode can create arrays as well.

Comment: No disrespect to anyone involved but simply making the first element of an array the json object is NOT solving the OP's issue - yes,  json-encode can produce arrays - but what you have posted here doesn't help the OP much.  @enobrev

Comment: And I want ice cream.  Anyhow, this question is answered in the duplicate link, Samad, see above where it says "possible duplicate"

Comment: @Samad - that is **VERY** rude = "i want an anwer".  Can you not see people are trying to help you already?  Be pacient.

Comment: Lix, what's wrong with my (updated) answer? Is it still wrong? It generates the requested (wanted :) output.

Comment: @biz - Yep, now it looks ok :) (removed downvote)

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit too quick with the first answer.